# Nest php if/else statement in variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I want to put an if/else statement in an include but it doesn't work out. The result is the statement published as plain text.

See [this page](https://www-d-o-t-cactusfestival-d-o-t-be.alvast-online.nl/test/sample.php).

**Basis file sample.php**

```
<?php include "include.php";?>
<?php $name = "Menu 1";?>
<html>
<body>      
<?php echo $showMenu ;?>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Include file include.php**

```
<?php
$showMenu='if($name=="Menu 1")
{echo "Menu 1";}
else
{echo "Menu 2";}';
?>
```

If I'm right the problem is situated in the include.php file, but don't know how to adjust the if/else statement in the include to make it work. If you put the if/else statement inline in the sample.php file it works though.

Comment: That's not the right syntax. See the basic `if` syntax at https://php.net/if

Comment: `$showMenu = ($name === 'Menu 1' ? 'Menu 1' : 'Menu 2');` thats all I want to share.

Comment: A couple issues: (a) `$showMenu` is just a string and will not be evaluated by normal means. (b) You're `include`-ing your second file *before* `$name` is set in the original file - the results will not be as you expect. All in all, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of some of the most foundational constructs in PHP, and I'd encourage you to go back and review the PHP manual for things like [the `if` construct](http://php.net/if).

Comment: Your `if/else` syntax is incorrect. The way you're doing it `$showMenu` is going to render that as a string. It looks like you're trying to do a ternary if: `$x = $valid ? 'yes' : 'no';`

Comment: Hi and welcome, perhaps you could outline what you are trying to achieve, there may be a better alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put code in a string and expect it to be executed.  You *could* use `exec` to execute a string, but everyone will tell you to **never** use `exec` unless you fully understand the repercussions.

What you could do above is:

```
if ($name == 'Menu 1') {
    $showMenu = 'Menu 1';
} else {
    $showMenu = 'Menu 2';
}
```

Then `sample.php` would have to look like this:

```
<?php 
    $name = 'Menu 1';
    include 'include.php';
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <?= $showMenu ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats code in a string, so not really code.

Its better practice to make that code into a function

include.php

```
<?php
function showMenu($name)
    if($name=="Menu 1") {
        $ret = "Menu 1";
    }else{
        $ret = "Menu 2";
    }
    return $ret;
}
?>
```

Then in any code that includes that file you can call that function. It also means that the code wont be run until you actually call it rather than running it just because the include file was included in another script.

```
<?php 
include "include.php";
?>
<html>
<body>      
<?php echo showMenu("Menu 1")?>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't work this way.

You need to use standard if/else statements and from there you can either echo your desired result or concat the string to a variable that you can then use later for whatever you want.

You can do it like this as a basic starting point:

```
<?php
if ($name == "Menu 1")
{
    echo "Menu 1";
}
else
{
    echo "Menu 2";
}
?>
```

An even sexier approach would be to use the ternary operator, string concatenation and or use custom functions but one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are probably using PHP 5 and you come from the JS World. You can't assign a variable to a function, as you do in Javascript. The best solution then would be  as follows:

sample.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php include('include.php'); ?>

    <?php show("Menu 1"); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

include.php

```
<?php


function show($string){
  if($string == "Menu 1"){
    echo "Menu 1";
  }else{
    echo "Menu 2";
  }
}


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion of using a function, however that didn't work out.
I solved it by putting the php if/else statement to another file, and than call the include, which works perfect for now. I'll try to make the function work as that seems to be a more professional solution.